# disable specific days returned by php-mysql in jquery ui datepicker

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui

I have this jquery:

```
$.post('booked_dates.php', function(data) {
 var bookedDays = data;
    });

    function isAvailable(date){
    var dateAsString = date.getFullYear().toString() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1).toString() + "-" + date.getDate();
    var result = $.inArray( dateAsString, bookedDays ) ==-1 ? [true] : [false];
    return result
  }

   $('#cal').datepicker({minDate: 0, maxDate: "+2M", beforeShowDay: isAvailable});
```

and this php, with date being in y-m-d form:

```
$merchant_date = mysql_query("SELECT date FROM merchants");

    while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($merchant_date)){

        $date =  $result['date'];
    }
```

I was wondering how I can store all the dates in an array, pass the array to the Jquery side, and then that would disable the "booked" dates. Basically, how can I make available an array as data and store it in bookedDays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `json_encode()` the result from MySQL in your PHP file:

```
$merchant_date = mysql_query("SELECT date FROM merchants");
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($merchant_date)){
    $dates[] =  $result['date'];
}
echo json_encode($dates);
```